# Pickle - Unable to correctly store appended dictionary to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pickle

I am trying to save a list of multiple dictionaries in a pickle file and by able at any time to store a new appended dictionary in the list and save it in the pickle file and then load the pickle file as a list of dictionaries. So far, the code behaves as follows:

The first time I try to append a dictionary in the list, the pickle file looks like this (the data is saved succesfully):

```
Running info()......

===================================================
Existing data: []
===================================================

Running save_score()......

Inside try: {}
============================================
Existing data: [{}]
New data: {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}
Saved Data: [{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}]
===================================================
```

The second time I try to append a dictionary in the list, the pickle file looks like this:

```
Running info()......

===================================================
Existing data: [[{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}]]
===================================================

Running save_score()......

Inside try: [{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}]
============================================
Existing data: [[{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}], [{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}]]
New data: {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}
Saved Data: [[{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}], [{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}], {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}]
===================================================
```

As you can see (the values in the dictionary are not a concern in the example above), instead of appending to the existing list, everytime, a new list inside the list is created. So far, I have not managed to fix this and get the expected output.

The expected output should be:

```
Saved Data: [{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}, {}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}]
```

Instead, the output is:

```
Saved Data: [[{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}], [{}, {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}], {'ComputerName': 'computer name', 'PlayerName': 'user 1', 'ComputerScore': 3, 'PlayerScore': 1}]
```

***Code is as follows:***

```
import pickle

data = []
computer_name = "computer name"
username = "user 1"
computer_score = 3
human_score = 1

def save_score():
    try:
        existing_data = pickle.load(open("w6_project.p", "rb"))
        print("Inside try: {}".format(existing_data))
        data.append(existing_data)
    except (OSError, IOError) as e:
        pickle.dump({}, open("w6_project.p", "wb"))
    new_data = {"ComputerName": computer_name, "PlayerName": username, "ComputerScore": computer_score, "PlayerScore": human_score}
    print("============================================")
    print("Existing data: {}".format(data))
    data.append(new_data)
    print("New data: {}".format(new_data))
    pickle.dump(data, open("w6_project.p", "wb"))  # Save the data into a pickle file
    print("Saved Data: {}".format(data))
    print("===================================================")
    pass

def info():
    try:
        existing_data = pickle.load(open("w6_project.p", "rb"))
        data.append(existing_data)
    except (OSError, IOError) as e:
        pickle.dump({}, open("w6_project.p", "wb"))
    print("===================================================")
    print("Existing data: {}".format(data))
    print("===================================================")
    pass

def main():
    print("Running info()......\n")
    info()
    print("\nRunning save_score()......\n")
    save_score()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have two lists - `data` and `existing_data` - and you join them in wrong way. Using `append()` you put one list inside another list. You should use `extend()` to join them

```
 data.extend(existing_data)
```

or shorter

```
 data += existing_data
```

But if you add new data after loading pickle then you should simply assing directly to variable

```
 data = pickle.load(...)
```

---

**EDIT:** Minimal working example

```
import pickle

computer_name = "computer name"
username = "user 1"
computer_score = 3
human_score = 1

def save_score():
    
    try:
        data = pickle.load(open("w6_project.p", "rb"))
        print("Inside try: {}".format(data))
    except (OSError, IOError) as e:
        data = []
        
    new_data = {"ComputerName": computer_name, "PlayerName": username, "ComputerScore": computer_score, "PlayerScore": human_score}
    data.append(new_data)

    pickle.dump(data, open("w6_project.p", "wb"))  # Save the data into a pickle file

    print("============================================")
    print("Existing Data: {}".format(data))
    print("New Data: {}".format(new_data))
    print("Saved Data: {}".format(data))
    print("Length Data: {}".format( len(data) ))
    print("===================================================")

def info():
    try:
        data = pickle.load(open("w6_project.p", "rb"))
    except (OSError, IOError) as e:
        data = []
        
    print("===================================================")
    print("Existing Data: {}".format(data))
    print("Length Data: {}".format( len(data) ))
    print("===================================================")

def main():
    print("Running info()......\n")
    info()

    print("\nRunning save_score()......\n")
    save_score()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: solved! Thank you very much for the provided information.